# Xamarin Forms:ImageCircle package is not working in release mode UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, circleimage

For the circle image, I am using **Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle** package and it is working fine in debug mode.

But in release mode, all the pictures are in square format. I uninstall and reinstall the nuget. Also, do clean, rebuild and deleting bin and obj folders, but still the issue is not resolved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into this piece of the [documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin#final-builds).

> For linking you may need to add:
>
> **Android:**
>
> ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Android;
>
> **iOS:**
>
> --linkskip=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.iOS --linkskip=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions

Add this to your platform project build options.

**Android**

[image: Add linking skip on Android]

**iOS**

[image: Add linking skip on iOS]

You should only need to add this on the Release configuration.

For UWP, you just have to create a small, trivial reference to the CircleImage assembly to keep it included in a release build. Add this piece of code above the Xamarin.Forms Init line:

```
var rendererAssemblies = new[]
{
    typeof(ImageCircleRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
};
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, rendererAssemblies);
```

Comment: I have only problem with UWP, android and IOS working fine

Comment: Updated to include UWP

Comment: How to add multiple init codes at a time in App.xaml.cs for UWP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758644/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-multiple-init-codes-at-a-time-in-app-xaml-cs-for-uwp